# Error while invoking Sagemaker Model : Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model Error

Tags: google-colaboratory, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to connect to Laama2 Model hosted in AWS sagemaker. For some of the basic things it work ok. However when I am using Retrieval Augmenter retrieval and passing the relevant document to get the right prediction. It is giving me the following error.

```
*Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (1986 > 1024). Running this sequence through the model will result in indexing errors*
```

Here is my code:

```
urls = ['https://www.mosaicml.com/blog/mpt-7b',]
        from langchain.document_loaders import UnstructuredURLLoader
        loaders = UnstructuredURLLoader(urls=urls)
        data = loaders.load()
        from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
        text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(separator='\n',
                                              chunk_size=500,
                                              chunk_overlap=50)
        docs = text_splitter.split_documents(data)
        embedding_model = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name='sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
        VectorStore = FAISS.from_documents(docs, embedding_model)
        llm=SagemakerEndpoint(
             endpoint_name=endpoint_name,
             region_name=region,
             model_kwargs={"max_new_tokens": 700, "top_p": 0.9, "temperature": 0.6},
             endpoint_kwargs={"CustomAttributes": 'accept_eula=true'},
             content_handler=content_handler
         )
        chain = RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain.from_llm(llm=llm, retriever=VectorStore.as_retriever())
        chain({"question": "what is MPT model series?"}, return_only_outputs=True)
```

It is getting the right response sometimes, otherwise generating gibberish ( not taking the passed content into consideration)